# Why does my type not load in ASP.Net site?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to make a few changes in an C# ASP.Net web site.

I know C# and .net 3.5 but with this I am not very familiar.

When I run this program I get this error:

```
 Cannot load type FredCK.FCKeditorV2.Uploader
```

at the line:

```
 <%@ Page language="c#" Trace="false" Inherits="FredCK.FCKeditorV2.Uploader" AutoEventWireup="false" %>
```

I tried to put the FredCK.FCKeditorV2.dll in the Bin folder but nothing changed.

What could I do to solve this?

Comment: What's the full error message?  Have you referenced that assembly in your project?

Comment: How can i reference the assembly  in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the assembly containing this class is referenced in your project and added to the `<assemblies>` section in your web.config (don't forget to adjust the version and PubliKeyToken to match those of your assembly):

```
<assemblies>
    ...
    <add assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXX" />
</assemblies>
```

Comment: This is already defined like this
`<%@ Assembly Name="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B0*************" %>`

Comment: @user596711, where is it defined? Is it before the `<%@ Page` directive? I guess not as IIRC you cannot have other directives before it. Also what does the `System.DirectoryServices` that you have shown has to do with your problem?

Comment: Sorry the is not the definition. Can you direct me to where it should be?

Comment: I really sorry to bother you but i cant find a web.config file

Comment: @user596711, it's should be at the root of your web application.